# How to fix "member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type"?

Tags: c#, wpf

'Search': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type showing but unable to spot the bug in the XAML or the Code

This is a new window in WPF project, tried to find if there are any methods that has the same name as the class.

XAML:

```
<Window Name="Search" x:Class="Library.UI.Search"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Library.UI"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Search" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Background="DarkGray">
        <TextBox Name="SearchTxtBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="10,42,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="622"/>
        <Button Name="SearchBtn" Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="637,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Height="22"/>
        <Label Name="SearchLbl" Content="Search Book" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20"/>
        <RadioButton Name="JournalRadBtn" GroupName="SearchType" Content="Journal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="637,21,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="JournalRadBtn_Checked"/>
        <RadioButton Name="BookRadBtn" GroupName="SearchType" Content="Book" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="637,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="True" Checked="BookRadBtn_Checked"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

XAML.CS:

```
public partial class Search : Window
{
    public Search()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

     private void BookRadBtn_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchLbl.Content = "Search Book";
    }

    private void JournalRadBtn_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchLbl.Content = "Search Journal";
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same name for the window (`<Window Name="Search"`) and the code-behind type (`public partial class Search`). That's what the compiler is complaining about. Change one or the other and it'll work.

Comment: That's because when you use the name attribute on an element in Xaml, it gets declared in the auto-generated part of the partial class you're working in.